# Apache mod_wsgi permissions issue

Tags: django, apache, permissions

I have a setup like the following:

wsgi.py file : `/srv/apache/wsgi.py`

Django project code: `/srv/www/mysite.co.uk/{Django_apps}`

and I have an `apach2.4` virtual hosts file as [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7205556/). From the logs and from `ps -ef|grep apache` it appears that apache runs as `www-data` (consistent with Ubuntu 13.10 I believe). Yet, if I set permissions on the wsgi.py file and dir as follows:

```
 /srv root.root 755
 /srv/apache www-data.www-data 700
 /srv/apache/wsgi.py www-data.www-data 400
```

The site breaks with an error :

```
[pid 3993:tid 139745498285824] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=3993, process='mysite.co.uk', application='www.mysite.co.uk|'): Call to fopen() failed for '/srv/apache/wsgi.py'
```

Why is this? (Infact even permissions 700,700 for apache and apache/wsgi.py still fail, only if I allow `other` access with something 755, 444 do things work).

Comment: Have you tried www-data 770? I wonder if your launching with the right user/group. When you launch apache check the user/group the process is launched under using 'ps aux | grep apache'.

Comment: Apache server child processes runs as a special user and the apache user 'www-data' must be able to read the WSGI script file, hence we need to set chmod o+r for wsgi

Comment: The special user is what I call 'djangoUser'. In the end what worked was: `/srv/apache : www-data.www-data 755`, and `/srv/apache/wsgi.py: djangoUser.djangoUser 400`. Only the child process djangoUser needs to be able to read `wsgi.py`, but it's necessary for apache to be able to ls and cd to the dir (rx) I think because of the `<Directory "/srv/apache">` block. Thus it's necessary for both djangoUser and www-data to have rx permissions on `/srv/apache` and necessary for djangoUser to have `r` on the wsgi.py file.